# Grabbing state value inside another module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I created 2 modules:

- Auth
- User

When a user is being logged in, I retreive the firstname and lastname which I store as:
state.auth.user.firstname and state.auth.user.lastname.

As I created a view which shows the user data in HTML, I want to retrieve user information through the User module with the following function:

```
const getters = {
  currentUserAccount(rootState){
    return rootState.auth.user;
  }
};
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Can someone tell me what I can do best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rootState is passed via 3rd argument

```
const getters = {
  currentUserAccount(state, getters, rootState){
    return rootState.auth.user;
  }
};
```